# Could someone explain how async works with belongsTo/hasMany relationships?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I had this code in my ember app:

```
var FooModel = DS.Model.extend({
    bars: DS.hasMany( 'bar', { async: true, inverse: 'foo'} )
});

var BarModel = DS.Model.extend({
    foo: DS.belongsTo( 'foo', { async: true, inverse: 'bars'} )
});
```

**Edit**: Using

```
Ember      : 1.13.7
Ember Data : 1.13.8
```

But when I went to render `foo.bars`, they wouldn't be loaded unless I used the browser back and forward buttons. Reloading the page would cause the `foo.bars` to disappear again.

When I changed the code to this:

```
var FooModel = DS.Model.extend({
    bars: DS.hasMany( 'bar', { async: true } )
});

var BarModel = DS.Model.extend({
});
```

Everything works as it should, and I'm just really confused as to why. Especially since I took that original code from another ember app where it was working just fine (although there might have been some adapter/serializer magic going on that I don't know about). **Edit**: The app where it was working is using

```
Ember      : 1.4.0
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba
Handlebars : 1.3.0
```

**Edit**: Using REST adapter for both

Comment: what ember(data)-version are you using? which adapter (REST f.e.) ? maybe shouldReloadAll = false?

Comment: @Jeff I knew I was forgetting some kind of important info. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have replied a similar question [What is an “async relationship”? / `{async: true}` vs. `{async: false}`](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107/14?u=ppcano)

### Async relationships (default)

Accessing the relationship will return a promise.

```
post.get('comments').then((comments) => {
  // now we can work with the comments
});
```

If the data is not available and the relationship is accessed (for example, from a template or a "consumed" computed property), Ember Data will automatically fetch the resources.

Read more about [Relationships as Promises](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises)

### Sync relationships (from docs)

Ember Data resolves sync relationships with the related resources
  available in its local store, hence it is expected these resources
  to be loaded before or along-side the primary resource.

#### BelongsTo

```
  export default DS.Model.extend({
    post: DS.belongsTo('post', {
      async: false
    })
  });
```

In contrast to async relationship, accessing a sync relationship
  will always return the record (Model instance) for the existing
  local resource, or null. But it will error on access when
  a related resource is known to exist and it has not been loaded.

```
  let post = comment.get('post');
```

#### HasMany

```
  export default DS.Model.extend({
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {
      async: false
    })
  });
```

In contrast to async relationship, accessing a sync relationship
  will always return a [DS.ManyArray](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.ManyArray) instance
  containing the existing local resources. But it will error on access
  when any of the known related resources have not been loaded.

```
  post.get('comments').forEach((comment) => {
  });
```

If you are using `links` with sync relationships, you have to use
  `ref.reload` to fetch the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Async in relatioships

`{ async: true}` is the default value for relationships in Ember since 1.13 which means that in most cases you define the relationship without specifying the async value at all. It means that related records will not be loaded into the store until required. This is almost always the desired way to go since it prevents blocking by returning a promise. Remember that promises require a different way of programming since the process no longer is procedural step by step through the code. You manage promises by chaining a `.then(function(param){// handle fulfilled promise here});`.

There are cases where `{ async: false}` could be beneficial. For example in a one to one relationship and you wanted both sides of the relationship to be loaded immediately.

Why your code does not work

I don't know for sure but it seems that the code as you have written it and it could be a bug in the code. The same as with async above you also do not actually need to specify the inverse value here either. According to Ember documentation:

> Ember Data will do its best to discover which relationships map to one another. [Explicit Inverses](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/defining-models/#toc_explicit-inverses)

Your application as a simple one to many relationship should work fine simply with:

```
var FooModel = DS.Model.extend({
    bars: DS.hasMany( 'bar' )
});

var BarModel = DS.Model.extend({
    foo: DS.belongsTo( 'foo' )
});
```

Comment: Didn't know about `{ async: true }` being the default now. I've read the Ember explicit inverses docs a couple of times, and I think I get it, but maybe I'm still missing something. Anyway, I think this helps, thanks!